# Handling REST subresources with Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am creating a rest application and I have a resource called "job" which has a fixed set of sub-resources:

```
http://domain.com/api/job/1/
http://domain.com/api/job/1/phase
http://domain.com/api/job/1/owner
```

I am currently creating my REST API using Flask's MethodView. But I can not decide which is the best way to do the mapping. Should I use a separate class for each sub-resource like this:

```
class ApiJob(MethodView):
    def get(self, job_id):
        pass
class ApiJobPhase(MethodVIew):
    def get(self, job_id):
        pass
class ApiJobOwner(MethodView):
    def get(self, job_id):
        pass

app.add_url_rule("/jobs/<int:job_id>", view_func=ApiJob.as_view("job"), methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule("/jobs/<int:job_id>/phase", view_func=ApiJobPhase.as_view("phase"), methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule("/jobs/<int:job_id>/owner", view_func=ApiJobOwner.as_view("owner"), methods=["GET"])
```

Or should I handle all the sub-resources through the Job class like this:

```
class ApiJob(MethodView):
    def get(self, job_id, res_id):
        if(res_id == None):
            # deal with the "job" resource
        elif(res_id == "phase"):
            # deal with the "phase" sub-resource
        elif(res_id == "owner"):
            # deal with the "owner" sub-resource
        else:
            # unknown subresource return some HTTP error code

apl.add_url_rule("/jobs/<int:job_id>/", view_func=ApiJob.as_view("job"), defaults={"res_id": None}, methods=["GET"])
api.add_url_rule("/jobs/<int:job_id>/<string:res_id>", view_func=ApiJob.as_view("jobres"), methods=["GET"])
```

Which one you think is better and why? If you think that both are bad, is there any better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The first one is better. Why? 1) You don't have `if-else` statements in `get()` method. 2) Let's imagine you will have post/put/delete methods for each view in future(one more 'if-else'?). 3) 1 class - 1 responsibility is a better than 1 class for different responsibilities. I also like to use [@api.resource()](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L397) decorator.